# No root file defined at installation

Tags: installation, 13.10

I'm a complete stranger with Ubuntu, and i've run into a problem with installing.

What I am trying to do, is to install Ubuntu 13.10 to my old laptop. This laptop has a new hard-drive, that is completely empty. So no Windows or other operating systems to work with.

I'm booting my computer with USB, and it starts normally, but ass I press "Install Now" instead of "Try Ubuntu", then those problems really start. It gives me message "No root file system defined.." etc.

What to do?

Comment: You have to prefer some installation guide of Ubuntu, if you don't know how to install. Actually it is not that much tough, you've to select **`/`** from the selection list as one of the mount point, in order to install Ubuntu. I hope [this](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/) and [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux) links would help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on "install" now , choose the third option which reads `Something else`. Select the partition (which is your new hard disk) , if the partition has not been created, create it by clicking `Add` button , set "mount point" to `/` and partition type to `ext4 journal`. I would recommend you to create one more partition as `swap` partition. Then select your `ext4` partition and click `install now`. You are ready to go..!